# Append space between Currency symbol and value

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatting

I am formatting my decimal value as MydecimalValue.ToString("c"). 
I am able to format it correctly, now i need to append a space between the currency Symbol and Value.

For example

```
 decimal mynum = 123;
 string s = mynum.ToString("c")
```

it displays $123
I need it as $ 123 .. ie $123 to $ 123

Pls help

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
 decimal mynum = 123 ;
 string tet = string.Format("{0:c}", mynum).Replace(" ","").
                       Replace(mynum.ToString(), " " + mynum.ToString());
```

The Actual cause is, your currency setting is set in that way. Instead , you set as in the below image

[image: Currency Setting]